# Knockout.js custom binding for slideshow: images not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js, slideshow

I'm building a slideshow of images with previous and next buttons. The images are fetched from a json object. The images display fine without any problem using `<img data-bind="attr: { src: images } />` but as soon as I apply `return { controlsDescendantBindings: true }`, the images stop displaying. And the data-bind on the `<img data-bind="attr: { src: images } />` doesn't work anymore.

Do you know what's happening?

Many Thanks

HTML:

```
<!-- carousel -->
<div class="carousel" data-bind="carousel: true">
    <div class="controls">
        <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
        <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="viewport">
        <!-- trip() represent the json object, but it's confidential -->
        <ul data-bind="foreach: trip().boat.decks">
            <li><a href="#"><img class="image" data-bind="attr: { src: images }" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
 <!-- carousel -->
```

Knockout/JS:

```
// binding for carousel
ko.bindingHandlers.carousel = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var $carousel = $(element),
            $viewport = $carousel.find('.viewport'),
            $controls = $carousel.find('.controls'),
            $prev = $controls.find('.prev'),
            $next = $controls.find('.next'),
            $slideList = $viewport.find('ul'),
            $slide = $slideList.find('li');

        console.log('carousel starting...');
        console.log('what is element: ', element);
        console.log('what is $element: ', $(element));

        // put active on 1st slide
        $slide.first().addClass('active');

        //TODO: prev btn
        $carousel.on('click', '.prev', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log('Prev btn carousel clicked!');

            $viewport.find('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');

            // if arrived at 1st slide, start again from last slide
            if ($viewport.find('.active').index() < 0) {
                $slide.first().removeClass('active');
                $slide.last().addClass('active');
            }
        });

        //TODO: next btn
        $carousel.on('click', '.next', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            console.log('Next btn carousel clicked!');

            $viewport.find('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

            // if arrived at last slide, start again from 1st slide
            if ($viewport.find('.active').index() < 0) {
                $slide.last().removeClass('active');
                $slide.first().addClass('active');
            }
        });

        return {
            controlsDescendantBindings: true
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Why are you returning `controlsDescendantBindings: true` if you want Knockout to handle child bindings in the normal fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return `controlsDescendantBindings: true` you tell Knockout not to perform bindings on child elements, that's why no child elements are bound. The [documentation on creating custom bindings that control descendant bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html) states that:

> Normally, bindings that use controlsDescendantBindings will also call ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(someBindingContext, element) to apply the descendant bindings against some modified binding context.

However, in your case you never call `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants`, so Knockout will never bind child elements.

I'm not sure why you are trying to control descendant bindings in the first place, but you need to either remove that or ensure that call you `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants` if you want Knockout to bind child elements.

Comment: Thanks for theresponse @robert.westerlund. I'm using the `controlsDescendantBindings: true` because, I wanted to make the `click` event on the `prev` and `next` button to work, they wouldn't work if I didn't use it. Unless my understanding of custome binding is off-track...

Comment: You do not need to do `controlsDescendantBindings: true` even if you want to listen to events on child elements (though for elements which are dynamically added you should probably use `on` with a selected and scoped to a parent). However, I would probably make your carousel using either a [view model and template version](http://jsfiddle.net/7bsVd/) or a bindingHandler which uses an already existing jQuery UI plugin or similar to create the actual carousel.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @robert.westerlund. I'm a beginner in Knockout so I didn't really understand custom bindings

Comment: You could make it into a [self contained bindingHandler](http://jsfiddle.net/j7BLv/) as well, but I still suggest creating a bindingHandler which uses an existing jQuery UI carousel plugin or similar. At least, if you do create a bindingHandler, do try to make it less dependant on having the exact correct child DOM elements, and if it is dependant on those the bindingHandler should probably create those child elements itself instead of requiring the user of the bindingHandler to know the exact structure expected.